# jQuery create variable to use in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that returns a variable. That returned variable I want to use in the second function.

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong here:

So what I did is this:

```
function setSearchUrl(searchUrl){
  var $select = $('.navbar-form.navbar-search select');
  $select.on('change', function(){
      searchUrl = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      $(this).closest('form').attr("action", searchUrl);
  }); 
  return searchUrl;
}

function liveSearch() {

 var e = $(".navbar-search input").val(),
 query = e.replace("/", "-slash-"),
 url = setSearchUrl(searchUrl) +'/?search=' + query + "&format=json"


    $.getJSON(url, function(e) {
      // etc etc etc ....

}   

$(function() {

  var searchUrl;
  setSearchUrl()

});
```

This returns an empty `searchUrl`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. The url will only be determined when the select option is changed. You have to perform the search *inside* that "change" handler.

Comment: if you are returning a value from function store it in a varaible eg: var x = setSearchUrl(); so you can use it further by passing it to liveSearch(x) as a argument

Comment: @Pointy: Well that's exactly the idea. When somebody enters a search word and then choose a category (via select) then there should be an url string created based on those values. That `liveSearch()` performs the actual search based on that url. Otherwise the search will be triggered everytime even when we don't want to. Or don't I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: @Chaitanya Ghule: Is it possible to create an example perhaps? Where should I set that `var x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Just check below code..

Just for demo -

Based on select value url gets generated dynamically to send an ajax request.

```js
function setSearchUrl(selVal) {
  let searchUrl = selVal;
  return searchUrl;
}

function liveSearch(searchUrl) {
  console.log(searchUrl);
  /*
   Your code for ajax request
  */
}

$(function() {
  $('#select').on('change', function() {
    let selValue = $(this).val();
    if (selValue !== '') {
      let searchUrl = setSearchUrl(selValue);
      liveSearch(searchUrl);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='select'>
  <option value=''>Select URL</option>
  <option value='example.com/abcd.php'>URL1</option>
  <option value='example.com/pqrs.html'>URL2</option>
  <option value='example.com/wxyz.asp'>URL3</option>
</select>
```

Hope, this works for u.. :) :)

Comment: `return searchUrl = 'example.com/abc.php';`  why the `searchUrl = `?

Comment: it was not necessary but just to set some value to show OP a demo of using   a variable returned by one function in another function..

Comment: Anyways your example does not explains the implicit / explicit ways of referencing to a changing variable value. - See OP's code to see how he struggles with the change event.

Comment: ya u are correct but OP just said how to access returned variable value.

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan: You are correct that value can change anytime! Can you point me to some directions perhaps?

Comment: @Meules i have updated my code to set url value dynamically on select value.